# Weird string on OS X Terminal prompt prefix ($PS1)

Tags: bash, security, prefix

I have recently noticed that I get weird prompt prefix strings when I open the Terminal, for example: `ilcdtl57gy784w:~ username$`.

I can trace back the value to `/etc/bashrc`, I can see that `$PS1=\h:\W \u\$` but I don't remember explicitly setting that value. Is that due to some update? Or could that be some security vulnerability.

Has anybody experience this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

that string is your hostname. Your computer is getting a weird name (probably assigned from DHCP) and that is what you're seeing. You can change `\h` in `$PS1=\h:\W \u\$` to something else if you want to hardcode the string there.